# Does Julia's TcpSocket support proxies?

Tags: sockets, proxy, julia

Quick question.

Does Julia in any way support sockets with proxy?
I was unable to find anything like this.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by "supports proxies". A socket either receives or sends network packets. Those packets may or may not go to other machines that act as proxies. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Send and receive packets through proxies.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by *"Send and receive packets through proxies"*. A socket either receives or sends network packets. Those packets may or may not go to other machines that act as proxies. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I basically want to connect to a server under a proxy, so that all traffic goes through that proxy before reaching the destination.

Comment: what kind of [proxy implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Implementations_of_proxies) are you referring to? web proxy?